# How to Retain Non Sorted Array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to retain the original array? 
I have this array

```
let array = [2, 1, 5, 4],
    sorted_array = array.sort();
```

And when i log it

```
console.log(array) //this will return the sorted one.
```

Is there any way to retain the original array? or i'm just doing it wrong..